# An unusual integral involving Hermite polynomials

Tags: integration, hermite-polynomials

I want a closed and nicely form for the following integral

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{-x^2}{2}} He_n(x)He_m(a(x-b)),
$$

but I didn't  find this guy inside the Ryzhik's book.

Comment: sad but true....I'm trying to use the generating function, but until now have not been lucky. Thanks @YuriyS

Comment: @YuriyS I made a mistake,

Comment: Okay, now I have hope.

Comment: The Ryzhik's book has a similar Integral, https://imgur.com/a/bhf1c, but I think this integral can't help me,

Using the generator function I can find an integral that exists in the book, but after that,  I get stuck.
$\sum_n\frac{t^n}{n!}\int dx e^{-x^2/2} H_m(x)H_n(a(x-b)) = \sum_n e^{-t^2/2 -\alpha bt +\alpha t^2/2}\int dx e^{-(x-\alpha t)^2/2}H_m(x)$

Comment: See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485888352) (open access) equation (32). You will be able to express $He_m (a(x-b))$ as a finite sum of $He_j (x-b)$ and then apply the integral formula you found in Gradstein

Comment: Thanks @YuriyS. I believe this expansion will help me to solve the integral.

Comment: If you do, you can post this as an answer to your own question. It could be helpful for other people browsing this site

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky one.  It requires both the Hermite multiplication theorem
$$
\operatorname{He}_n(ax) = n!\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor }\frac{1}{2^kk!(n-2k)!}a^{n-2k}\left(a^2-1\right)^k \operatorname{He}_{n-2k}(x)
$$
and the shift
$$
\operatorname{He}_m(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k}y^{m-k}\operatorname{He}_k(x).
$$
Using these two, the integral becomes
$$
I_{nm}=\sum_{k=0}^m{m \choose k}(-ab)^{m-k}k!\sum_{l=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor }\frac{a^{k-2l}(a^2-1)^l}{2^ll!(k-2l)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\operatorname{He}_n(x)\operatorname{He}_{k-2l}(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx.
$$
Care must be taken when attempting to apply orthogonality
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\operatorname{He}_n(x)\operatorname{He}_{k-2l}(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}n!\delta_{n,k-2l}.
$$
Note that the maximum $k-2l$ is $m$ when $k=m,l=0$, so $m\ge n$ for this integral to be non-zero.  Furthermore, when $l=0$ we get the highest Hermite polynomial combination $\operatorname{He}_n(x)\operatorname{He}_k(x)$ so $k$ must be at least $n$, hence we can start the sum at $n$:
$$
I_{nm}=\sum_{k=n}^m{m \choose k}(-ab)^{m-k}k!\sum_{l=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor }\frac{a^{k-2l}(a^2-1)^l}{2^ll!(k-2l)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\operatorname{He}_n(x)\operatorname{He}_{k-2l}(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx.
$$
Starting the sum here also has the side-effect of imposing that the integral is zero when $n<m$.  Now we can apply orthogonality and set $n=k-2l$, but note that this will not always have integer solution for $l$, which can be seen by looking at the parity of this condition $\operatorname{mod}(n - k + 2l,2) = 0$, or $\operatorname{mod}(n,2) = \operatorname{mod}(k,2)$, the summation index k must have the same parity as $n$.

We will denote the parity of $n$ as $p=\operatorname{mod}(n,2)$, as it will appear in the solution.  We could break this into two cases: even $n$ and odd $n$, and you may argue that the answer looks nicer, but we will continue to keep it general, at the expense of some notational burden.

To keep only the terms that will result in a non-zero integral, we must either choose $n = 2s$ or $n=2s+1$.  To be general, we take $n=2s+p$.  Simultaneously we use the orthogonality and get the final answer:
$$
I_{nm}=\sqrt{2\pi}a^n\sum_{s=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}^{\left\lfloor \frac{m-p}{2} \right\rfloor }{m \choose 2s+p}\frac{(2s+p)!}{2^{s-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}\left(s-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right)}(-ab)^{m-2s-p}(a^2-1)^{s- \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}
$$